# Intuit IPP not working on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, intuit-partner-platform

I have an existing web app using the IPP .NET SDK for QuickBooks v3.0. It works fine on my current host. But I am now trying to move my app to Azure. I have a page that queries the several QB entities like customers and vendors and returns them to Kendo Grids. Again this works fine in my current hosting environment. But on Azure, these don't return any data and I am at a loss to figure out how to debug it.

I have tried setting the trace log and request response logs in the web.config file to point to the azure file system like below, but no dice...no logs are written.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <!-- To turn on/off intuit cloud sync logging-->
      <add name="IPPTraceSwitch" value="4" />
      <!-- values are a range from simple to verbose; 0 - 4. 0 is off, 4 is verbose-->
    </switches>
    <!-- turn to true or false to turn on intuit api call tracing -->
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="2">
      <listeners>
        <add name="IdsTracer" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener,System,Version=4.0.30319.1,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=ffff" initializeData="D:\home\site\wwwroot\Logs\Intuit\Trace\QBAPITrace.log" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <intuit>
    <ipp>
      <logger>
        <!-- To enable/diSable Intuit Request and Response log -->
        <requestLog enableRequestResponseLogging="true" requestResponseLoggingDirectory="D:\home\site\wwwroot\Logs\Intuit" />
      </logger>
    </ipp>
  </intuit>
```

I've tried to setup Remote Debugging per [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/). But when I put in the Qualifier, it does ask for my user and pwd, but then essentially hangs while displaying a popup box "Operation is Taking Longer than Expected"...and it never gets to the point of listing the w3wp.exe process (or any processes for that matter).

Are there any changes that need to be explicitly changed for IPP to work on Azure?

Comment: Can you download fiddler2 from google and run it alongside your azure code to see what request/response is logged there?

Comment: @nimishashrivastava it is only capturing the front end request to pull the data...essentially it calls a controller action which is logged...but then the backend server does the call out to intuit to get the data. That call is not visible to fiddler from what I can tell, and that seems to make sense...unless I am missing something???

Comment: Fixed by manually adding the log file directories using FTP client. Then logging worked.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by manually adding the log file directories using FTP client. Then logging worked.